# Is there an Emacs mode which highlights differences from the committed version?

Tags: minor-mode, version-control

One feature that Xcode has which I think is pretty neat is a "Comparison" mode, which continually shows differences between the current buffer and the most recent commit.

[image: Comparison mode]

Is there anything like this for Emacs?  I don't really care about the simultaneous side-by-side views.  Just highlighting the background of any lines that were changed would be a great help.

I know I can always do `C-x v =`, but it's a static view of one point in time, and only shows the diffs.  I want to see my entire file, editable, with the diffs highlighted.

Answer (score 33):

Dmitry Gutov's [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) library provides `diff-hl-mode`, which gives you the fringe highlighting shown in the top window in the following screenshot (with the actual diff displayed in the bottom window for comparison):

[image: diff-hl screenshot]

It uses the generic `vc` functionality in Emacs in order to be VCS-agnostic. The readme says "Tested with Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and SVN. May work with other VC backends, too."

Note that `diff-hl-margin-mode` can be employed if you're using terminal Emacs rather than GUI Emacs.

By default `diff-hl` only highlights the differences between the *saved* file and the repository; but `diff-hl-flydiff-mode` enables un-saved differences to be highlighted as well, so that you can see the changes while you edit.

Also note the built-in (to standard Emacs) `highlight-changes-mode`. That doesn't really tackle your problem out-of-the-box, but the `highlight-compare-*` functions might facilitate a solution.

Comment: #33 has been resolved.

Comment: Dmitry: Indeed -- I've actually been trying it out over the past few days, and I can confirm that this feature works very well :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it; it was written by one very patient contributor. Thanks for updating the answer!

Comment: Oh wowzers thank you @Dmitry, that's a gem of a diff package! For everyone else here, confirm that the package is still maintained by Dmitry for the 9 years since the answer has been posted, last commit 3 weeks ago as of March '24. As for the tramp warning in the README,, maybe it sometimes slow, but perhaps nothing of significance with the modern 100Mbps+ speeds. I am an active tramp user (working w/ cloud VMs), and see no issues w/ this package.

Answer (score 11):

You don't specify what version control system you're using, but if it's git, ou can use [git-gutter](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter) to put an indicator in the margins when a line has been added, deleted or modified.  It's available in MELPA via `M-x package-install git-gutter`.

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I was imagining, but it seems like it only updates the gutter when the buffer is saved.  I wonder how hard it'd be to integrate with (or otherwise act more like) flymake...

Comment: Ditto. This would be even better if it would automatically add `+` as soon as you make changes rather than wait for pressing all those buttons to save.

Answer (score 10):

You should check out [Ediff](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EdiffMode).  It can both display diffs and act as a (3-way) merge tool.  It lets you easily revert changes, and also highlights refined differences to show you only the parts of each hunk that actually changed.

[image: screenshot of ediff]

`ediff-revision` will let you easily compare against the most recent commit, or any previous commits.